# Put dynamic data in v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to add a string from an array to `v-model`, something like this:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
 <input :v-model="item.key" />
</div>
```

but this code doesn't work and after many time search I didn't find a right way to do this

Answer (score 0):

See this [fiddle for a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/wezL6pcg/). `v-model` doesn't need the `:` in front.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    items: [{
        key: "test one"
    },
    {
        key: "test two"
    },
    {
        key: "test three"
    }]
  }
})
```

and the dom:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
   <input v-model="item.key" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Docs link: [Vue form bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html)